# Transaction using Jena API on Fuseki SPARQL Endpoint does not actually modify the database

Tags: transactions, sparql, rdf, jena, fuseki

I want to use transactions to execute insert/update/delete queries on a SPARQL endpoint. The problem is that the changes are not actually saved to the endpoint.

If I run this small example program:

```java
    public void test1()
    {
        Dataset dataset = DatasetFactory.create("http://localhost:3030/demo");
        System.out.println("Supports transactions = " + dataset.supportsTransactions());
        System.out.println("Triples before: " + dataset.getDefaultModel().size());

        dataset.begin(TxnType.WRITE);

        UpdateRequest request = UpdateFactory.create(
            "INSERT DATA { <http://example.org/b68d359eb001> a 123 }");
        UpdateExecution.dataset(dataset).update(request).execute();

        try
        {
            dataset.commit();
        }
        catch (Throwable throwable)
        {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            dataset.end();
        }

        System.out.println("Triples after: " + dataset.getDefaultModel().size());
    }
```

It outputs:

```
Supports transactions = true
Triples before: 1178
Triples after: 1179
```

We can see that the new triple was added to the dataset object. However, if I run the program again, I get the exact some output, so the triple was not actually saved to the database. If I run the same query using Fuseki UI, it saves the triple without a problem. Am I running the transaction incorrectly?

I followed the documentation: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/txn/transactions_api.html (see the largest code snippet there). Note that I need to make updates by using SPARQL queries, not via Model etc.

Comment: what is the backend? Is it just an RDF file loaded in-memory on startup of Fuseki?

Comment: `DatasetFactory.create("http://localhost:3030/demo")` loads the file into an in-memory dataset. If you want to work with the remote store, try `RDFConnection`.

Comment: @UninformedUser, yes, I just ran "fuseki-server", went to localhost:3030, and uploaded RDF N3 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was able to solve it by not using transactions but instead putting all the queries (I have several that need to be executed) into one `UpdateRequest`. If any of the queries fails, the entire request fails:

```java
UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
statements.forEach(updateRequest::add);
UpdateExec.service("http://localhost:3030/demo").update(updateRequest).execute();
```